# How to remove the target variable from PCA 2D -biplot

Tags: python, pca

I wanted to draw 2d biplot using my data set (credit card churn data set). But my diagram includes my target variable also as a feature. How can I remove it?

[image]

Dataset sample showing the headers
[image]

I have attached the code I've used

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from bioinfokit.analys import get_data
from bioinfokit.visuz import cluster
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
# load iris dataset

df=pd.read_csv(r'G:\\Edu\\My academics\\MSc in CS\\3rd sem\\Research\\Python files\\PCA.csv')
df.head(2)
df.loc[df['Attrition_Flag'] == 'Existing Customer', 'Attrition_Flag'] = 0
df.loc[df['Attrition_Flag'] == 'Attrited Customer', 'Attrition_Flag'] = 1
df.Attrition_Flag = df.Attrition_Flag.astype(int)

X = df.iloc[:,0:4]
target = df['Attrition_Flag'].to_numpy()
X.head(2)


X_st =  StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
pca_out = PCA().fit(X_st)

# component loadings
loadings = pca_out.components_
print(loadings)


# get eigenvalues (variance explained by each PC)  
print(pca_out.explained_variance_)


# get biplot
pca_scores = PCA().fit_transform(X_st)
cluster.biplot(cscore=pca_scores, loadings=loadings, labels=X.columns.values, var1=round(pca_out.explained_variance_ratio_[0]*100, 2),
    var2=round(pca_out.explained_variance_ratio_[1]*100, 2), colorlist=target)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about dropping the target column after `target = df['Attrition_Flag'].to_numpy()`?

I.e. `df.drop(columns=['Attrition_Flag'], inplace=True)`

Comment: I tried that too, but still getting the same graph

Comment: Try print the content of the dataframe `X` right before `X_st =  StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)`, see if the target still exists in it (i.e. check if the drop is successful).